# How to increment counts of one table by getting counts from another table using update in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have two tables

one is **business_details**

```
+--------------+--------------++--------------+
| msisdn       | total_counts || id           |
+--------------+--------------++--------------+
| 919999999999 |         0    ||    2323232   |
| 918888888888 |         0    ||    2323231   |
| 917777777777 |         15   ||    2323233   |
+--------------+--------------++--------------+
```

and another table  is: **users_details**

```
+--------------++--------------+
| msisdn       || id           |
+--------------++--------------+
| 919999999999 ||    2323232   |
| 918888888888 ||    2323231   |
| 917777777777 ||    2323233   |
+--------------++--------------+
```

I want to update table '**business_details**' and set total_counts = total_counts + (the counts from users_details where business_details.msisdn = users_details.msisdn and business_details.id
= users_details.id)

**Can anyone help to increment to the counts of one table by matching two conditions from another table?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer to your question is to use `join` in an `update` statement.

I am going to guess that total counts in the user table refers to the number of rows.  This requires aggregation before the `join`:

```
update business_details bd join
       (select ud.msisdn, count(*) as cnt
        from user_details ud
        group by ud.msisdn
       ) ud
       on bd.msisdn = ud.msisdn
    set bd.total_counts = bd.total_counts + ud.cnt;
```

Comment: Thanx for the help :-)